# Multiple processes reporting signals received

Tags: signals

If I run multiple programs with `program &` in one terminal, and then from another one start sending `SIGKILL` `SIGINT` or any other signal, will the terminal running all the processes tell me what process received what signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal is not aware of the signals sent to such processes thus won't tell you anything. But if your shell has job control, it can tell you when a background job terminates (e.g. due to the signal). For instance, with bash and zsh, you need to setopt the `notify` option so that you get such a report immediately (instead of waiting for the next prompt).

You can also set up a SIGCHLD trap, which is executed when a background job terminates (but you won't be able to get any information on the terminated job with the trap).

In POSIX shells, you can also use `wait $pid` to get the exit status of some PID `$pid` (which will give you the signal, with possibly false positives and false negatives, depending on what the process does), with some limitations. See the [`wait` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html) for more information.